# Oracle select max record after value

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have such table. I must find max date (max_date_6) for no='000000001    001' and status=6. and the date (max_date_1) for status=1 which this date is after  max_date_6. I write query such,but it gives only max for two statuses. but max_date_6 must be 20943 and max_date_1 must be 21002

```
WITH max_date_6 AS
(
         SELECT   no,
                  Max(DATE) date_6
         FROM     TABLE
         where    status=6
         AND      no='00000001   001'
         GROUP BY no ), max_date_1 AS
(
         SELECT   no,
                  max(DATE) date_1
         FROM     TABLE
         WHERE    status=1
         AND      no='00000001   001'
         GROUP BY no)
SELECT date_6,
       date_1
FROM   max_date_6,
       max_date_1 where date_6<=date_1
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want the *minimum* date for status = 1 where that date is greater than the *maximum* date for status = 6.

Answer (score 0):

No need to make things complicated here, you just need two MAX's with case's:

```
SELECT Max(case when status = 6 then DATE end) as date_6,
       Max(case when status = 1 then DATE end) as date_1
FROM   TABLE
where  no='00000001   001'
```

Edited version, now required date_1 > max(date_6), which means null will be returned if no date_1 > max(date_6), otherwise same result as previous.

```
SELECT Max(case when status = 6 then DATE end) as date_6,
       (select Max(DATE)
        from TABLE
        where status = 1
          and no = t1.no
          and date > (select max(date) from TABLE
                      where no = t1.no
                        and status = 6)) as date_1
FROM   TABLE t1
where  no = '00000001   001'
```

Comment: but it will give me only max dates for each status.will not?

Comment: Yes, max date where status = 6, and max date where status = 1. Isn't that what you asked for? If not, please specify the exact result you want!

Comment: I want to find max date for status=6,but for status=1 i want find max date which is after max_date_6,not only max

Comment: jarlh , i want explain a bit.if for status =6 the max_date is 74632,and for status=1 there are three records in date column 88642,89543 and 72213 .i must find for status=1 max_date_1=88642 but not 89543 .but your query will give max only

Comment: You mean the smallest date_1 that is larger than date_6? Change MAX to MIN in the sub-select. (I.e. row 2).

Comment: it gave exception "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

Answer (score 0):

So you want maximal `date` for `status=6` and `date` for `status=1` from row **preceding** that one.
It's impossible unless you have some order in which rows are gathered. For this reason I added column ID (maybe you have some other key, but hid it).
So the input data is:

```
NO                TDATE STATUS ID
----------------- ----- ------ --
00000001   001    21223      1  1
00000001   001    21041      1  2
00000001   001    21002      1  3
00000001   001    20943      6  4
00000001   001    20939      6  5
00000001   001    20933      1  6
00000001   001    20943      6  7
```

Query and result:

```
with t001 as (select * from input where no = '00000001   001'), 
t6 as (select * 
  from (select id, tdate from t001 where status = 6 
    order by tdate desc, id) 
  where rownum = 1)
select t6.tdate max_date_6, t001.tdate max_date_1
  from t6, t001
  where t001.id = (
    select max(id) from t001 where status = 1 and id<t6.id )

result:
MAX_DATE_6  MAX_DATE_1
----------  ----------
     20943       21002
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the minimum date for status = 1 where that date is greater than the date for status = 6.

Comment: @ David Faber Here he wrote something other: *for status=1 there are three records in date column 88642,89543 and 72213 .i must find for status=1 max_date_1=88642 but not 89543*. 88642 is nor min, nor max. I created my answer based on example from main post. Words *after* and *max_date_1* are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Given your expected data, tt sounds like you want the *minimum* date for status = 1 where that date is greater than the *maximum* date for status = 6.

```
WITH m6 AS (
     SELECT max(tdate) AS max_date_6
       FROM mytable
      WHERE status = 6
        AND no = '00000001   001'
)
SELECT min(m1.tdate) AS max_date_1, m6.max_date_6
  FROM mytable m1, m6
 WHERE m1.status = 1
   AND m1.no = '00000001   001'
   AND m1.tdate > m6.max_date_6;
```

Alternately:

```
WITH m6 AS (
     SELECT no, max(tdate) AS max_date_6
       FROM mytable
      WHERE status = 6
      GROUP BY no
)
SELECT min(m1.tdate) AS max_date_1, m6.max_date_6
  FROM mytable m1 INNER JOIN m6
    ON m1.no = m6.no
   AND m1.tdate > m6.max_date_6
 WHERE m1.status = 1
   AND m1.no = '00000001   001';
```